# Flutter: How to get the users address from contacts

Tags: flutter, settings, android-contacts

I've guessed the Users Address from their GPS, looking up their location using Google's Places, but the output of that is pretty variable (no locality oftentimes, outside cities a consistent locality field would be helpful to my app).  The thing is I do *NEED* the users home address for my app to work, but they may not be at home when they download the app.

I'd prefer to get their address from contacts.  I've looked at a couple of Flutter plugins for accessing the address book, flutter_contacts, etc., but I can't see how you simply get the users details.  So how do I request the Users HOME address, HOME email, MOBILE phone, whatever I can get from the device?  Age might actually be beneficial too, so I could pivot the app to the needs of those who are using it.

I feel this is such a commonly useful thing it should have its own special permission, rather than the blunt one of exposing their entire contacts address book.  So is there a better way of doing it?  Less invasive so the user can more easily consent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a special contact called "Profile" that contains the user's details if they bothered to add them on their phones, but in most cases it'll be empty, and anyway, accessing the user's profile requires the "Read Contacts" permission.

It'll be strange to ask the user for the "Read contacts" permission without they understanding why on earth would your app require such a permission "to guess your address" is not a very good reason.
And I suppose might cause some users to uninstall and/or flag your app as potential spyware.

If you app relies on having the user's address, you should instead simply pop a dialog with a question to the user to fill out their address manually.

Comment: Thanks @marmor, that's a complete answer.  I've got the address from GPS and asked the user for confirmation.  Allows me to display the app to the user, without putting up a form barrier.  Surprised there isn't a simpler solution for the user.